# Check my answer - show a function is integrable and find the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, proof-verification

Let $Q =[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Let $f: Q \to \mathbb R$ defined as such:

if $(x,y) \in \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ then $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}$ where $x=\frac{m_1}{n_1}$ and $y=\frac{m_2}{n_2}$ are reduced fractions.

if either $x$ or $y$ are irrational, then $f(x,y)=0$.

Show that $f$ is integrable over $Q$ and find $\int\int_Q f(x,y)dxdy$

What I did:

Step I: if $(x,y) \in \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ then $f$ is not continuous at $(x,y)$.

Proof: $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}$ but $\lim_{\alpha \to x} f(\alpha,y)$ does not exist, since if $\alpha$ is irrational then it's zero, but if $\alpha$ is rational then its something else. At any rate, if $\alpha$ is irrational then $f$ is zero and not $\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}$

Step II: if $x$ or $y$ are irrational then $f$ is continuous

Proof: I could use a hand with this. I don't know for sure why this is true. $f(x,y)=0$ but $\lim_{\alpha \to x,\beta \to y} f(\alpha,\beta)$ doesn't necessarily have to be zero. they could be rational. I know that the "probability" of them being irrational is a lot greater, but this is not a formal proof.

conclusion: the set of points in $Q$ at which $f$ is not continuous are just the rationals, and that set is countable, and so it is negligible - meaning that $f$ is integrable over $Q$.

$\int \int_Q f(x,y)dxdy = \int\int_{Q \setminus \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q} f(x,y)dxdy = \int\int_{Q \setminus \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q}0dxdy=0$

Is the integral correct? and how do I fix the hole in my proof.

Comment: Just for clarification, we are strictly talking about Riemann integration, and by negligible set I mean that its of zero measure.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should change your domain $Q$ to $(0,1]\times(0,1]$, since $f(x,y)$ is not well-defined when $x$ or $y$ is zero.

In Step II, we can show that $f$ is continuous at irrational points as follows. Let $x,y\in (0,1)$ be irrational and suppose that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$. Observe that for any rational $p,q\in (0,1]$, there are only finitely many $p',q'\in (0,1]$ such that $f(p',q')\ge f(p,q)$. Hence, given any subsequence of $\{f(x_n,y_n)\}_{n\ge1}$, we can select a further subsequence that converges to zero. This implies that $f(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow 0=f(x,y)$ and thus $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)$.